# respond_to and redirect_to not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form which is set up with form_for and remote: true.

```
<%= form_for(@vocab, url: user_vocab_path(@user, @vocab), remote: true)  do |f| %>
```

As expected the respective update action in the vocab controller processes the request as JS:

```
Processing by VocabsController#update as JS
```

Then the mystery happens. In the case of valid data I want to redirect the user . With a standard HTML request. I guessed s.th. like this should work, but it doesn't:

```
def update
    @user = current_user
    @vocab = @user.vocabs.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
     format.js { redirect_to home_user_path(@user), format: 'html' }
    end 
end
```

The home action in the UsersController also processes the request as JS. With or without the format specified in the redirect. Can s.o. explain me why?

I read all the Rails Guides and the API but couldn't get anything out of it.

Comment: Try using format.js { window.location.href = "/users/#{@user.id}/home"  }

Comment: Didn't work `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method 'window' for #<VocabsController:0x007fd062af0c28>):`

Comment: @BachanSmruty You can't just switch to JavaScript inside Ruby code, that obviously will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to respond to a request for js with a html file. I think you basically want to have a none remote behavior (a redirect) for a remote form. So changing `format.js` to `format.html` and removing the `remote: true` should be a solution. If you want to do a frontend redirect (which means another request has to be send) you could try using

`format.js { render inline: "window.location.href = '#{home_user_path(@user)}'"}`

Comment: You need quotation marks around your JavaScript. You cannot freely mix Ruby and JavaScript in the same file.

Comment: @Daniel Schmidt: Actually I need both. Originally the respective action should respond with JS in case of invalid data (error messages) and with a html redirect in case of valid data.  Is it possible? See also this question I postet yesterday : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612481/respond-to-confusion/28612557#28612557

Comment: @Flip If so, the format.js ... part I mentioned should work fine.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, that works out fine. Vielen Dank! Do you happen to know why a `redirect_to` with the format option set to 'html' doesn't work here? As I read in the API this should do what I am doing with JS now, right?

Comment: Well not exactly, but as far as I know the redirect_to sends a redirect header and I don't think that the JS will interpret this. You could give it a try and stop at the callback of the AJAX and look if there is a redirect header set on the response object. That way you could do this redirecting without having to inline JS all the time.